# rs232 to ethernet converter connection issue with Atmel board

Tags: ethernet, serial-communication, atmel

we are doing a project for receiving data from a device using a RS232 to ethernet converter (gridconnect net 232+) onto to a Atmel board. When we connect the converter to the PC, we are getting the output but not when connected to the microcontroller board. We need to know if there has to be some network confirguration to be done on the converter in order to receive it on the microcontroller.

Thanks !

Comment: This seems more like a "how do I use/connect my XYZ device?" than a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with that board or device, but with any RS-232 communication channel you should check that all RS-232 parameters are set up correctly **on both sides**.  Databits, stopbits, parity settings, etc.  Even one setting being off will completely stop RS-232 communications.

Once that is done, I'd hook up a terminal emulator of your choice to simulate the microcontroller side and make sure that you're getting the right traffic from the Ethernet side.  You might get lucky at that point and everything might start working.  ;)